# Deploying and setting up SQL Express 2008

Tags: installation, sql-server-express

Looking into installing an instance of SQL Express for an app.  I want to have a separate installer. (I need to run some Transact-SQL stuff afterwards)

I've been referencing this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd981032(v=SQL.100).aspx).

> It is recommended that you ship the Express package extracted on your media and then launch Setup.exe directly. To extract the Express package, run the following command.

So far I tried bundling the unpackaged SQL Setup in an MSI (using a `Setup and Deployment` project).  The user installs, which just puts the extracted files in a folder, then in `OnAfterInstall` I'm the setup process.  This doesn't work since SQL's Setup.exe runs some .msi files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to make my own executable to bootstrap the installation and use [FreeExtractor](http://download.cnet.com/FreeExtractor/3000-2250_4-10050237.html) to create a self-extracting zip of the setup and my bootstrapper and then run my executable at the end.